# How to delete rows using a key word from columns in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, row, dataframe, multiple-columns

How we can delete the whole row taking a keyword in any column of that row? I have 250 such rows and 28 columns and I want to delete all rows having "income" as a key string in any column from a data frame using pandas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say for instance you wanted to drop any row that had 'c' in a column

```
In [5]: import pandas as pd
In [7]: data = [['a', 'b'], ['a', 'c'], ['c', 'd']]
        df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['col1', 'col2'])

In [9]: df
Out[9]:
  col1 col2
0    a    b
1    a    c
2    c    d

In [10]: df.loc[~(df == 'c').sum(axis=1).astype(bool)]
Out[10]:
  col1 col2
0    a    b
```

Comparing different solutions for this problem. I first created a large test data set:

```
In [11]: data = [['a', 'b'], ['a', 'c'], ['c', 'd']]*10000
         df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['col1', 'col2'])
```

Here is an updated solution and I think the best so far:

```
In [6]: %timeit df.loc[~(df == 'c').any(axis=1)]
100 loops, best of 3: 3.85 ms per loop
```

Here is my original solution:

```
In [13]: %timeit df.loc[~(df == 'c').sum(axis=1).astype(bool)]
100 loops, best of 3: 3.92 ms per loop
```

Here is the comparison from the other solutions:

```
In [14]: %timeit df[df.applymap(lambda x: False if 'c' in str(x) else True)].dropna()
10 loops, best of 3: 43 ms per loop

In [5]: %timeit df[~df.apply(lambda series: series.str.contains('c')).any(axis=1)]
10 loops, best of 3: 60.7 ms per loop
```

Though the original problem is relatively simple, it also illustrates that lambdas can be very slow. There is a high overhead to calling a function multiple times, for instance if there is a lot of rows in a dataframe. Avoiding them is often worthwhile when dealing with large dataframes.

Comment: Thanks, I was reviewing and marked your answer correct that I forgot earlier. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have no other NA values in your df, this will work substituting 'DELETE' with 'income'

```
df[df.applymap(lambda x: False if 'DELETE' in str(x) else True)].dropna()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply` together with a lambda expression to check for the target word in each column.  Then use `any(axis=1)` to locate any row containing that word.  Finally, use boolean indexing with a tilda (`~`) to locate all rows where income is NOT in the row.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'income', 'c'], 'B': ['a', 'b', 'income'], 'C': ['a', 'b', 'c']})

>>> df
        A       B  C
0       a       a  a
1  income       b  b
2       c  income  c

# A check for which cells contain the target word.
>>> df.apply(lambda series: series.str.contains('income'))
       A      B      C
0  False  False  False
1   True  False  False
2  False   True  False

# Remove the offending rows.
>>> df[~df.apply(lambda series: series.str.contains('income')).any(axis=1)]
   A  B  C
0  a  a  a
```